# Unable to use Python Module I compiled

Tags: linux, package, shared-libraries, python-3.6, python-module

Using a build.sh file and a setup.py file, I am attempting to build and run a Python Module. When I run my build.sh file, it will compile all my source code and give me a message that the package is installed.
[package being installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii5TV.png)

However, when I try to import the package in python, it gives an import error saying "ImportError: libl8_angles.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."

[no such file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llHLk.png)

Another interesting thing is that when I cd to the irectory above it, I can import the package without error, but then when I try to run the package, it tells me that the package doesn't have the attribute of the method I am trying to import.

[no attribute error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BIF0.png)

[The github link to my package is here](https://github.com/Swordman51/l8angles-package-linux)

I've tried renaming the library I'm building and edditing the setup.py file, but I keep getting the same errors.